# Help me improve my question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1125017/what-general-function-can-i-use-to-represent-the-next-sequence-2-2-2-2-2-3-3-2), and several people stated that it is not clear enough. So I fixed all what they been asking me to, but I did not got a feedback if my fix is satisfiable.

Please tell me if the question is clear enough or should I add additional modifications?

My goal is to find solution for:

$$f'(n)=\begin{cases}
a &\text{if $n \bmod c=0$ or in the range of  $\{c-d,c-1\}$}\\
b &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
$$\frac{e}{n}=y - \sum_{0}^{n}{f'(n)}$$

- $a,b,c,d,e,y$ are known positive integers

I want to get $n$ representation with $a,b,c,d,e,y$

Comment: For me it is too unusual to have the derivative ($f'$) in such a functional definition so I just skipped and assume there are much more clever people around who'll have an idea how to deal with this. Maybe the question is ok, maybe not: I don't see it immediately but also see no obvious problem ...

Comment: The notation is very problematic. Especially the sum is probably meant to be
$$\sum_{i=0}^n f'(i) \ne \sum_{?=0}^n f'(n) = (n+1)f'(n)$$
Also, a "range" is usually an interval while $\{c-d, c-1\}$ is a set. Furthermore if you give such functional equations, you should give the domain of your function $f$. Is it defined on $\mathbb N$ or on $\mathbb R$ or on $\mathbb Z_n \simeq \{0,\ldots, n-1\}$? As-is it is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation is very problematic. Especially the sum is probably meant to be
$$\sum_{i=0}^n f'(i) \ne \sum_{?=0}^n f'(n) = (n+1)f'(n)$$
Also, a "range" is usually an interval while $\{c-d, c-1\}$ is a set. Furthermore if you give such functional equations, you should give the domain of your function $f$. Is it defined on $\mathbb N$ or on $\mathbb R$ or on $\mathbb Z_n \simeq \{0,\ldots, n-1\}$?
As-is it is unclear what you are asking. Try to provide *complete* information. Everything you are given, including the context under wich the question arose, can be helpful to understand the questions intent and to provide a good and useful answer.